# Rails, Omniauth and Facebook - "Email can't be blank" issue in production but not development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

Very simple question.

I have run into the "Email can't be blank" issue with my rails app/omniauth/facebook login. There are many questions on this, and among the answers is that some users give their telephone number and not their email addresses. However in my case, I have a facebook account open, with an email address that works fine with omniauth in development, but when I use it production it comes back email can't be blank. My credentials are correct.

Can anyone explain how you could have this combination of events?

edit: here is my controller code (keep in mind my devise model is "Member" and there is an associated profile model "User"

```
def provider
     auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     member_email_check = Member.find_by_email(auth.info.email)
     if member_email_check.present? && User.find_by_member_id(member_email_check.id)
     sign_in_and_redirect member_email_check
     return false
    else
       member = Member.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |member|
      member.provider = auth.provider
      member.uid = auth.uid
      member.email = auth.info.email
     end
   end

  if auth.provider == "facebook"
    if member.save
       unless User.find_by_member_id(member.id)
           User.create(:member_id => member.id,
                  :full_name => auth.info.first_name + " " + auth.info.last_name,
                  :first_name => auth.info.first_name,
                  :last_name => auth.info.last_name,
                  :email => auth.info.email,
                  :picture => auth.info.image)
           end
         sign_in_and_redirect member
       else
         session["devise.member_attributes"] = member.attributes
         redirect_to new_member_registration_url
       end
     end
   end

   alias_method :facebook, :provider

 end
```

SOLVED!

```
        config.omniauth :facebook, "<YOUR API KEY>", "<YOUR SECRET KEY>", scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name,first_name,last_name,gender'
```

just added the email scope and info_fields.

Comment: For anyone to be able to help, we'll need some code to read

Comment: I accept what you are saying in principle, but in this case I am not sure - what code is needed. If it works in development but not in production, the only code thats different are the API Key/secret. I am sure I have these inputted correctly. If it helps, here is my controller code.

Comment: It could be any number of other environment-related things too, like `config/environments/*` differences, the domain your Facebook application is set up with, etc. If I were you, I'd start dumping things to your logs.

Comment: Hmmm...sounds like a plan. Its really odd because the Linkedin and Google authentication work fine in both dev and prod

Comment: Your comment led me to the answer - the devise config and the hash I was using for production. You seem to need to add the scope and info_fields to the hash. Unfortunately I am uncertain why this works in production but without it it works in development (may a security issue?). Make yours an answer and I will give you the credit!

Comment: Oh, great! I think it'd be more helpful for others if you wrote an answer explaining the configs you're talking about, since I couldn't provide that context. I'm happy with the alleyoop :)